# Using a Class as ValueMember in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I have a ComboBox, which currently uses a simple class, containing *Name* and *ID*. *Name* is used as `DisplayMember` whereas *ID* is used as `ValueMember`. However, I would actually like to pass both the *Name* and the *ID*, when selecting an item, since this would spare me the operation of looking up the name later. Of course I could store those seperately, but that seems rendundat, since they come from the same place.

Hence arises my question: Is it possible to use the class (from which I get the Name and ID) as `ValueMember` for the `ComboBox`?

I was thinking something like this:

```
cboCategory.DataSource = viewModel.categoryOptions; // Type: BindingList<Equipment>
cboCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboCategory.ValueMember = ???   // <--- This is where I run out of ideas
```

My Equipment class looks like this:

```
public class Equipment
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public Equipment (int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `comboBox.SelectedItem` for getting selected instance of your class

Comment: @Fabio how do I get around the fact, that in my **ViewModel**, the property I want to set is of type `Equipment`, whereas `.SelectedItem` is not (at least not at compile time)?

Comment: While `SelectedItem` is of type `object` it still reference to the instance of type `Equipment`. You need just cast it: `var selectedEquipment = (Equipment)combobox.SelectedItem`

Comment: Ah, clever. I got it to work now, thank you. If you want the points for an accepted answer, feel free to make it an answer (rather than a comment). Otherwise, I will sum it up later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access selected instance with `SelectedItem` property of combobox.
Only you need is cast to `Eqipment` type before using because `SelectedItem` is of type `object`.

```
var selectedEquipment = (Equipment)combobox.SelectedItem;
```

You can use data-binding as well to keep your viewmodel "loosely coupled"

```
cboCategory.DataSource = viewModel.categoryOptions;
cboCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboCategory.ValueMember = "Id";

cboCategory.DataBinding.Add("SelectedItem", viewModel, "SelectedEquipment", true);
```

With data-binding `viewmodel.SelectedEquipment` property will be updated when you change selected item in combobox.

Comment: Thank you once again. I was so focused on the `ValueMember` property, that I completely missed the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way how you can achieve this with pure C# without adding third property where you combine *Name* and *ID*.
You can consider that 3rd property security like:

- Is it enough to have only `get`?
- Is it enough to have it `protected`?
- etc.

When you're using XAML or WinForms, there's `MultiBinding` mechanism  to achieve similar behavior. IMHO, multi-binding is in most cases overhead and it is more beneficial to create 3rd property.

So your class would look like:

```
public class Equipment
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public Equipment (int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Identifier
    {
        get { return Id.ToString() + " " + Name; }
    }
}
```

You can extent you **ViewModel** with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notify about *Identifier* change when *Name* or *ID* changes.

More sophisticated (if needed) will be returning array of objects instead of string so you wont lose data at conversion (`ID.ToString()`) <- require more memory.

Comment: I got it to work using Fabios answer. I am not quite sure what you mean by it not being possible?

Comment: Thought that your ViewModel is loosely coupled and doesn't have access to combobox instance.

Comment: @Noceo, make sure you upvote / select as answer for Fabio so others know the solution is found and know what helped.

Comment: @DRapp I did that now. I left the computer for the day, after my last comment (time zones you know^^).